# How can i add row to html table from a list of objects

Tags: javascript, html, css

The object created every time the submit button is clicked , and it pushed to the book_list array but i get messy when i loop in the list to create a row , how can i solve this ?
here is the link : https://jsfiddle.net/s7jmkeqL/

```
let book = new Book(title.value, authName.value, email.value, price.value, date.value, lang.value, radio.value);
book_list.push(book);

// create new rows
function createTd(content) {
  let td = document.createElement('td');
  td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content));
  tr.appendChild(td);
  table.appendChild(tr);
}

book_list.sort((a, b) => (a.date > b.date) ? 1 : -1); // sort the list by date

for (let i = 0; i < book_list.length; i++) {
  createTd(book_list[i].date);
  createTd(book_list[i].authName);
  createTd(book_list[i].email);
  createTd(book_list[i].title);
  createTd(book_list[i].type);
  createTd(book_list[i].price);
  createTd(book_list[i].lang);
}
```

Comment: I don't see you are creating any rows... `tr.appendChild(td);` - Where does `tr` comes from?

Comment: i think it remember the first element from the array and [book]as [book,book] and it push all of it to the table again <tr><td>[book,book]</td></tr> but i dont know how can i solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is, as soon as you create a `<td>`, you add it to a `<tr>` but you also immediately append this `<tr>` to your table. As a result, your table gets filled with `<tr>` containing only one `<td>`.

Also I rewrote your `for` loop so as to avoid repeating yourself, and also make the `book` keys dynamic, in case you want to add more later (rating, recap, etc. for instance)

```
let tr;

function createTd(content) {
  let td = document.createElement('td');
  td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content));
  tr.appendChild(td);
}

const keys = Object.keys(book_list[0]); // ["date","authName",...]

for (let book of books) {
  tr = document.createElement('tr'); // Create a new row for each book

  for(let key of keys) {
    createTd(book[key]); // Append all the cells in the same row
  }

  table.appendChild(tr); // Add the row to the table
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot ! this have worked as i wanted , how ever i added, book_list.shift();
after the button is clicked and it worked but your's is so simple and so effective and looks very professional .